# gnome 3 panel and menu fonts are too small

Tags: gnome3

Gnome 3 panel and menu fonts are way too small. (I like using menu's as long as I used mouse and keyboard. Touchscreen, now, that would be different) Is there a tool or extension or *anything* that can adjust those?

I did figure out one way to do it, after spending far too much time on this question. In gnome tweaks, font settings, first adjust (font) scaling until panel and menu fonts look good. Then set the rest of the fonts until whole desktop looks nice. But this is a clumsy way to do it. For one thing, you cannot change panel/menu font this way. Only size.

Is there any way to adjust those, short of *patching gnome 3 sources and recompiling the whole desktop*? As far as I can figure it out, that is the only other way...

Answer (score 4):

You may use [(GNOME) Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Tweaks), previously known as (GNOME) Tweak Tool. It's a graphical interface for advanced GNOME 3 settings.

You should get what you're looking for in this tool:

[image]
([screenshot source](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/42224/how-do-i-change-font-size-in-gnome/))

---

You may create a custom CSS override for the shell theme in your home directory and load it from there to change the font of the top bar (which is controlled by the shell theme). To do that follow the steps below.

1. Create a directory, say `MyTheme` in `~/.themes`.
2. Create another directory inside `MyTheme` called `gnome-shell`.
3. Create an empty document in this `gnome-shell` directory and name it `gnome-shell.css`.
4. Open this `gnome-shell.css` in a text editor and add the following lines

   ```
   stage {
       font-family: FONT_NAME, Sans-Serif;
       font-size: 14pt;
       color: #ffffff;
   }
   ```

   Replace `FONT_NAME` by a font of your choice and change the `font-size` to your liking (you may change colour too) and save the file.
5. Install and activate the **User themes** extension from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).
6. Go to **Appearance** section of Tweaks and click on the drop-down box next to "*Shell theme*". **MyTheme** should appear in the drop-down list. Select it.
7. Log out and log in again.

Comment: Indeed. Tweaks contains all fonts *except menu and panel fonts*. While you can use scaling factor to adjust them, there seems to be no other way to configure those. At least, since gnome-shell.css vanished somewhere...

Comment: @JuhaMäkinen Please try the steps I added to my answer and report back.

Comment: So should'nt this custom theme enherit some other theme?! How can a single font setting be used as a theme?

Comment: @BaselShishani It should inherit the *default* GNOME shell theme and override only its choice of font. You can add a `@import url("/path/to/ThemeName/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css");` at the beginning to inherit one specific GNOME shell theme.